# How to get array max count of nested object in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

doc mapping:

```json
    {
       "properties":{
          "appeal_id":{
             "type":"long"
          },
          "attribution_res":{
             "properties":{
                "identify_layer_tag_list":{
                   "type":"long"
                },
                "rule_id":{
                   "type":"long"
                },
                "scene_id":{
                   "type":"long"
                }
             },
             "type":"nested"
          }
       }
    }
```

`attribution_res` is nested, I want to get doc which length of `attribution_res` is max,

How do I write DSL, the version is `7.10.2`